# Salesforce Single Sign on metadata file's binding method can't change in to http redirect

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, salesforce1-platform

When I'm changing Service Provider Initiated Request Binding in to http redirect it's saving and displaying as http redirect. But when I looking in the metadata file it shows as below.

Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>

Is it normal behavior or we need to change it manually?
We need to set Service Provider Initiated Request Binding  as http redirect because we need to support mobile single sign on also. Can you please let me know the further steps that I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select HTTP Redirect as the binding on the config screen, you will see in the HTTP trace that it will actually do that. The generated metadata doesn't reflect this, this is a product bug. You can manually edit the generated metadata and replace the binding.

Comment: Do you have a bug report of this?

Comment: @jmrjulian Nope but SF dev team is aware of it.

Comment: According to SFDC, this is not a bug, and the Metadata XML is generated as expected. What you see on SFDC's Single Sign-On page describes how SFDC sends SAML Requests, while the downloaded XML describes the SAML Responses it expects.

Comment: @jmrjulian According to the dev team that owns this code, it's a bug. The metadata of SF acting as a SAML service provider reflects bindings for auth requests.

Comment: that's so strange. I'm currently going back and forth myself with support and R&D on this matter, and they have not acknowledged it as a bug. But they have explicitly stated that it behaves as expected.